# How to get project folder path in visual studio code extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to get project folder path in visual studio code extension but very difficult to find the answer. My code is not working. I do not know it is possible or not. I have checked in google no one answer for this question. Anyone know about this please help me to find the answer.

[image]

extension.js:

```
var vscode = require("vscode");
var path = require("path");

exports.activate = context => {
const findPath = 
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', () => {

   let findprojectfolderPath = vscode.workspace.uri.fsPath; // Not working

   console.log(findprojectfolderPath);

});
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Adopting-Multi-Root-Workspace-APIs

Comment: Getting confusion

Comment: getEditorInfo() this function not working in extension.js file.  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/master/basic-multi-root-sample/src/extension.ts

Comment: which line in `getEditorInfo()` is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get currently opened file's project folder path in visual studio code extension.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811209/how-to-get-currently-opened-files-project-folder-path-in-visual-studio-code-ext)

Answer (score 10):

I would like to update Pushprajsinh Chudasama's answer as `vscode.workspace.rootPath` is now **deprecated**. It is being replaced by `vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders` which returns an array of `WorkspaceFolders | undefined`. To retrieve the path to all your workspace folders, you may now use:

```js
vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders?.map(folder => folder.uri.path)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you open the folder, then you can get the `workspace` variable.

```
let folderName = vscode.workspace.name; // get the open folder name
let folderPath = vscode.workspace.rootPath; // get the open folder path
```

Comment: rootPath is deprecated

Comment: These lines only will work on single workspace condition...not work on multi workspace

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the path of the file currently is opened by the user, then you need this

```
console.log(vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.fsPath);
```

Read this documentation for information further: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextDocument

Answer (score 1):

This function gets the workspace directory for the file currently open. If there is no active editor or the file doesn't belong to a workspace, it returns `undefined`.

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";

function getDocumentWorkspaceFolder(): string | undefined {
  const fileName = vscode.window.activeTextEditor?.document.fileName;
  return vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders
    ?.map((folder) => folder.uri.fsPath)
    .filter((fsPath) => fileName?.startsWith(fsPath))[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As It turned out `vscode.workspace.rootPath` is deprecated and the only solution that I found so far is described in this answer

[VS Code extension - get full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569993/vs-code-extension-get-full-path#answer-53919833)

Answer (score 0):

You must change the code. Like the example below.

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('extension.search', (p: { fsPath: string }) => {

   // p is an object whose path is fsPath.

   console.log(p.fsPath);

});
```

---

[Maybe this link can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63823046/visual-studio-code-extension-get-extension-installed-path/75225811#75225811)

Answer (score 0):

```
            const folderPath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri
            .toString()
            .split(':///')[1].replace('%3A', ':');
```

It is what I have done, and it works very well.
Note that the unit (C) is not replaced. It's just the '%3A' by the corresponding character ':'.

But, this is an URI. So you can also use the `decodeURI` function.

```
        const folderPath = decodeURI(vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0].uri
            .toString(true)
            .split(':///')[1]);
```