# visual studio code extension get extension installed path

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In visual studio code extension code we want path of extension where it is installed in system

as in windows it is "%USERPROFILE%.vscode\extensions"

but in extension code how can we get it

Comment: on my linux system you can find the path to a program (for example an extension) by using the whereis command on the terminal. There is probably the same or a similar command in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You get the extension context object from `activate` method, and then call `ExtensionContext.extensioinPath`,

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#ExtensionContext

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem in making the extension.

First, in this file, make a command in explorer/context, like the code below:

```
 "contributes": {
 "commands": [
      {
        "command": "demo.pathFolder",
        "title": "Get Path folder"
      }],
    "menus": {
      "explorer/context": [
        {
          "when": "explorerResourceIsFolder == true",
          "command": "demo.pathFolder"
        }
  ]
 }
}
```

---

Then you have to change extension.ts code. Like the example below.

```
vscode.commands.registerCommand('demo.pathFolder', (p: { fsPath: string }) => {

   // p is an object whose path is fsPath.

   console.log(p.fsPath);

});
```

---

[Maybe this link can help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57843809/how-to-get-project-folder-path-in-visual-studio-code-extension)